# access the function outside the socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i am not able to access the function create outside the sockets.
i want to basically export it and use in the middleware by requiring it.

```
   socket.on('init', function (req) {
            database=mongoose.connection;
            var dbname=database.useDb(req.db);


    var Observer =dbname.model('ObserverEvent');

      exports.create = function (req, res) {
        var observer = new Observer(req.body);
        observer.user = req.user;
    observer.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
      } else {
        res.jsonp(observer);
      }
    });


}
```

Comment: You  must populate `exports` when the module is initialized.  You can't populate it in some async callback like you are trying to do.

Comment: yes you can, if you name the above file as socket.js , you can do something like   var s=require(socket);   s.create

Comment: You don't seem to understand that `.create()` won't exist until some time later (when `socket.on('init', ...)` eventually gets called) and the caller of `require('socket')` won't know when it actually exists so it can use it.  You don't assign properties to `exports` in an async callback.  Most (or all) of the time that won't work.

Comment: If you're so convinced you can do it the way you are doing it, then what is your question?

Comment: ok...now i understood....sorry for that.....do you know any alternative to this